# Which is better? Comparison

Tags: cpu, performance, desktop-computer

All right?

A friend asked me which option is best: a Dual Core 1.6 Ghz or a Q. Core 1.1 Ghz? Both of them with 4GB of RAM.

Do you have an ideia if, for having a higher Ghz rate the Dual Core can, possibly, be better than a Q. Core?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can the person who downvoted please explain why? It's a fair question. Maybe it's too obvious for you. If that's the case: why not answer it?

Comment: Not obvious at all; it depends on what you use it for. Which is better: a sportscar or a truck? And you didn't even tell us whether you want to race or to move your furniture to another city.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I am sorry. But my friend, for example, didn't explain to me what is the use for the computer: I just assume he wants to know which one will provide him the best performance! 

It's very logical when someone is gonna buy an equipment (in this case a PC) that the performance is what is gonna be more important and the person will buy the best possible, based on the money the person have to buy it.

The analogy you used doesn't match exactly. Although I understand your thinking process! But there are things that are just for general use. Otherwise I should say, I agree..

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, but, as I said, I understand your thinking process and in part I agree with it; that said: I'll try and be more specific for future needs! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quad core CPUs can perform 4 tasks simultaneously and Dual core CPUs can perform 2 tasks simultaneously, so at first, the Quad core CPU would be a better option but you have to also take clock-speed into consideration, a 1.6 Ghz CPU will perform faster then a 1.1 Ghz, but that all depends on the Memory available i.e. The more RAM, the more calculations the CPU can perform.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see Muhammed_Khan. It's not easy to say, really! It's for general use he wants the PC!